# How force Google Sheets to accept the text as TEXT FORMAT (and stopped autoformatting as number)

Tags: google-sheets

For example, when I paste:

```
+XYZ
```

in Google Sheets, it autoformats it:

[image]

I've tried different things (`Format>Plain Text`) but it doesnt work. I just want to get what I paste there as plain text. (i dont have predetermined format of what i paste there, the sentecne might start with `+` symbol, with `=` symbol or whatever. I just want it stopped formatting of inputed data).

I saw answers to similar questions, which suggest putting `'` or whatever. But i dont want to manually put some symbols in front of every line, as I paste hundreds of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately you cannot force Google Sheets to stop auto-formatting as number.**

### As an alternative

Use a different program to add en masse, a single quote `'` to every piece of data you want to paste in sheets.

*For example:*

*You can use a free online tool (like https://pinetools.com/add-text-each-line) to change the following text*

```
+123
=xyz
= + 345 - a
/@dfg
+ 123 - 100 = 23
```

*to this, which you can then paste in Google sheets (or a notepad for later use).*

```
'+123
'=xyz
'= + 345 - a
'/@dfg
'+ 123 - 100 = 23
```

Comment: Typing `'123` (single quote on the left) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this is to consider using `File > Import`

If you import a plain text file, like .csv or .txt, under "Separator character," you can pick what letter or symbol Google Sheets uses to separate cells.

Detect automatically: This will automatically find ways to split your data set. For example, it can detect fixed-width-formatted files.
Tab
Comma
Custom: Choose a custom character to split your data.

Click Import.

[reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)